# Laravel query builder. Returning nested structured data

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have some queries that take a while as the sets are huge.

Im now doing them without active record, directly through Laravel query builder.

When joining two tables together the fields from table B are merged into the results from table A.

Is there away to nest that data in a sub object or array?

e.g.

```
\DB::table('posts')
    ->select('posts.id', 'posts.title', 'comments.name', 'comments.id')
    ->where('posts.status', '=', 'PUBLIC')
    ->leftJoin('comments', 'posts.comment_id', '=', 'comments.id')
    ->get();
```

returns something like:

```
{
  id: 123,
  title: 'My post',
  name: 'Comment name',
  // ...
}
```

where i would like:

```
{
  id: 123,
  title: 'My post',
  comment {
    name: 'Comment name',
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Do you have the posts and comments as models as well? You could probably do this with relations and `with()`.

Comment: Without looping through the record set and implementing this structure yourself, I doubt it will be possible. The query builder simply returns a flat result set, similar to that you would get if you were to run the queries yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with Eloquent relationships.

Firstly, declare the relationships in your models. For example, in **Post.php**:

```php
class Post extends Model
{
    // ...     

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

Now you could use `with('comments')` in your query.

and it should return an object similar to what you wanted.

See [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships) in the docs, particularly the Eager Loading section.

Comment: Specifically asking for query builder... Not eloquent

Answer (score -2):

Instead of query builder i use with()

You need to define in your model Comment a function for Post

```
public function posts(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'posts_id');
}
```

then in your controller

```
$result = Post::with('comments')->where('status', '=', 'PUBLIC')->select('comments')->get();
```

Comment: Specifically asking for query builder not eloquent